# Method Not Allowed (405) while uploadFileTask to QuickBlox - (Android)

Tags: android, quickblox

My problem is I am using **QBContent.uploadFileTask(file, true, null, new QBEntityCallback()** to upload the file to QuickBlox. But I am landing on **onError(List list)**. Check pictures please.

1. This is I get in OnError Method: 
   [image]
2. Showing in Logcat: 
   [image]

   Here is my Code:

   protected void startLoadAttachAudio(final File file)
   {
       Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
       h.post(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {

   ```
           QBContent.uploadFileTask(file, true, null, new QBEntityCallback<QBFile>() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess(QBFile qbFile, Bundle bundle) {
                   System.out.println("Success");
               }

               @Override
               public void onSuccess() {
                   System.out.println("Success2");
               }

               @Override
               public void onError(List<String> list) {
                   System.out.println("Failed.");

               }
           });
       }//end of run
   }); //end of handler
   ```

   }

Comment: please post full log from logCat to https://gist.github.com for better understanding your issue. Why do use old QuickBlox Android SDK?

Comment: Check this please. https://gist.github.com/sheikhrashid/27a90215860d1279d3bf3ed0f7d9fa4a

Comment: you use very old version of QuickBlox Android SDK (it can contain issues, which were fixed in latest versions), please use latest version for check your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by Updating the SDK version of Quickblox

Answer (score 1):

You can use library for upload file, i am using android async http. For example:

```
public void UploadFile(CarrierFileInformation carrierFileInformation)
{
    String path = carrierFileInformation.GetSaveDir();
    File file = new File(path);
    if(!file.exists())
    {
        this.uploadedFile = true;
        Toast.makeText(this.activity, this.activity.getResources().getString(R.string.not_found_file), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    String link = Settings.DOMAIN + MethodNames.UPLOAD_FILE;
    RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
    try
    {
        requestParams.put(FieldNames.UPLOAD_FILE, file);
        requestParams.put(FieldNames.ORDER_ID, carrierFileInformation.GetOrderId());
        requestParams.put(FieldNames.TEST_ID, carrierFileInformation.GetTestId());
        requestParams.put(FieldNames.TEST_DETAIL_ID, carrierFileInformation.GetTestDetailId());
        requestParams.put(FieldNames.FLAG, carrierFileInformation.GetFlag());
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    asyncHttpClient.post(link, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            Log.e("t", "işlem tamam");
            uploadedFile = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            uploadedFile = false;
        }
    });
}
```

requestParams using for send params your webservice, file you know your file.
you can edit my function.

In build.gradle you have to add this code   compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9' in dependices bloc then sync.

Comment: But, quickblox has provided its on Methods, which do work perfectly and easily. Why I am getting Method Not Allowed in onError

Comment: It means that the requested URL does not accept the POST method. Try again with GET.